# How to add an image to website with the image address including you website

Tags: html, image, github, web

How do you add an image to you website so that the image address's domain is you website?
Such as;
https://**www.google.com**/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png
[Cick here because I am not allowed to embed pictures into my post because  don't have more than 10 points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niGX1.jpg)
And not like this;

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</emaxple>
</head>
<body>
<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/TyjVGZqfT_MuQh86xLiQtr6MIPeAJSmvOHnTpj7r2Go-V68dkOfw1zyZX_ZQo0j54O2jitom6mF94fFsiUC7UXNr_SznAk8WbYqiHogylNnPnFi9PR2qD8kaH5LCF05SzXpZ9PPzWQE128x8sz8kXuvtmnfrCwCWUCfgk-1NusQ_1qwQhGNj3EW_n9QaqO_2eryLyTJQzquIz0sRj8--80r8lFwrL8iFzSfri48Kpny1BWmbaxKAueurIfYOc8VyX4d2Do2QKat43wXOxWbaeCWjkvsahMDoLSwJbvHxLOSzRTfUOQH1etJsUGJQbt5cgbCcHhsKEQQiZ3qqf-rXSHkdeyb6QL4EMVJsvfU7k45cdRba1gq0w7uAfWovZSsSv65A_dvJtIHvmvCPmpNcwU2-uN7hGRyuMUl8g5gm3KA6FrxPLQ8v0gZCeLCGJ5Je8JoCVYQ8Z9wHm2qLlo6mGPu_NIarHz7H9m4KM_CftWaG_Q1d82U8OFDbVWBdBEjlR7sYVnDCMSb2oUXRioRahLaQjnQzRpVfacBUZNa_a5Amnw2txzI0ly8JfVcRu3TYCWA74bHGDPAs3ijRGh_Lk2ggJabOhZ9pGTl1_BbCp8ihCnQYLwwR2Smmwub55Kdv4CibSM57_dFe7bo3xNYjqzFEoZnebeX8xX7YWpNI1LiGK3jeZeeieDS9JAw=w328-h177-no?authuser=0">
</body>
</html>
```

How do I get a clean image address that includes my website domain on GitHub (exaple.com/media/photo.jpeg)?

I tried uploading the picture to Google Photo, getting the image address (supper long) and finding the source code, I tried it and ran in some problems when trying to view the source code. I tried CTRL + U, right click the source code but it was translucent. So then I went to a Google, then I went to the source code and looked at the URL, and I found this before HTTPS "view-source:" so I opened a new tab and typed that in (I actually copy and pasted it) then added the image address, and I got weird stuff (example (I am not going to show all of it because it just looks like gibberish, and it would be mean to make you scroll through all of that when you are helping me) ÒD±L’ƒ1”°¬OwÞ†Í
ú^¦0ÈD„K‡\j¦,äì‘T[µ0¨êê™&ŽîÍ÷eOk) so I check to make sure that when I upload the photo that Google did not change it to a .webp to save space, (which they did not it is still a .jpeg) and I made a new file on GitHub test.jpeg, and pasted the code. I saved it, and looked to see if it worked, which it did not (you can try if you want it should be a very low quality picture of green bean and yogurt [right here here is the link](https://cgit0d3r.github.io/test.jpg) ([also here is the original](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/tCE0wLTBWU8tbWrEfp_nDW3QsKbWmJ0dJ1GjX__k6IW9mt4YV_BtLPpRNel8fw4VmB73ka0JxRl1Wh4rYD5WvufNj4PPKOsAtZ25dvBNyGqXyCqU7Y-3OVyoTCoupq1y-ZOoLOc1eE9NxH0yYx_f8uyj3DvsPlr3LTp3pqxLZdnNFBi1ttSL6kQwyyyjxtz_8BeSWMWAeo1GjNw90h2Rvaf-HZxr0M_Nkp712KFscE51ZSnzlXQYO1GVNqRiu1jWJKtyIn66p3hpqg8dq3yDNeaQbhg9Ai_hm3V2iviQYhUfZq9anTw0J33H5Mw0PHQ4ViaZ4qViK8dyt7ooJkNHRfp-ZoVY0_VFqd09Gr26_d6PDqHj-MKdFz9PGYjt6xgHAL20Ytwu5L1irGBniQwRRzyOU8vAfHqFZCuKmOBm8aLL9W_l4Z0hHtmCD6qklDmygyUuVG_cdotd3T43ACV5xy7SDCcPD27IGG4b3JDne0RFnlF4makth3EU2Z5K3v-Iqs4JxC5QZlGycCFi0j7fjdszV_jFOsPk4x8DSDfCJuinYeX_49EKfElvicMlPXPrJm0CxPnBBSD0hm22aKxy0ZyzkTpjB7jXWxQZO06XyC-_gPyvaOADP0KYfgQyQnNNIER6WBlUbeswS-iVzbCj5ICPW0ncEJf8TVt9s8oBs5OZVFB3O_EUeFBKh60=w313-h169-no?authuser=0) )

Comment: You buy a domain. This question is strange and unclear. Read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the image and save it in the media folder after you can just do

```
<img src="./media/photo.jpeg">
```

For more info visit https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp

Answer (score 0):

For that you should get a domain name and host your picture